# Стартовое сообщение вк бот Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, бот

Не могу найти, как отправить стартовое сообщение в боте в вк...
Есть ли уже готовая функция для отправки стартого сообщения боту или чтоб появлялась кнопка start как в телеграм ботах?

Comment: Это делается в настройках сообщества на самом сайте, насколько я помню.

Comment: да, спасибо помогло